# "Error installing charlock_holmes" : "icu required"

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to install charlock_holmes on my Mac (10.7.5, ruby-1.9.3-p392), and I'm encountering the following error:

```
$gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9.4'
Building native extensions.
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/mthompson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -licui18n... no
checking for main() in -licui18n... no


***************************************************************************************
*********** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev) ***********
***************************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I've installed icu via macports, so my icu directories are `/opt/local/lib/icu` and `/opt/local/share/icu`. I've tried installing with the directories specified:

```
$ gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9.4' -- --with-icu-dir=/opt/local/lib/icu --with-opt-include=/usr/local/include/ --with-opt-lib=/usr/local/lib/
```

..but I hit the same error. Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Not sure but would those extra `--` cause any problems (I wouldn't think so but you never know).
Also, you could try installing ICU via [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/icu4c.rb) as suggested in the error text.

Comment: What does the mkmf.log file say?

Comment: I didn't want to install via Homebrew, as that required switching from Macports to Homebrew and reinstalling a ton of existing packages. However, I had considered doing that many times before for other reasons, so I decided to bite the bullet and switch. That resolved the issue. So long, MacPorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up switching from MacPorts to Homebrew and reinstalling my rubies and packages.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to install this gem using the version of ICU installed with macports and pointing `--with-opt-include` and `--with-opt-lib` to subdirectories of `/opt`.

The gem successfully installed by running:

```
gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9.4' -- --with-icu-dir=/opt/local/lib/icu --with-opt-include=/opt/local/include/ --with-opt-lib=/opt/local/lib/
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue today. I realize that the original issue was resolved by switching to Homebrew. That wasn't an acceptable solution to me, so I kept digging. The solution was actually quite simple.

After installing icu via Macports, simply install charlock_holmes by running:

`gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=/opt/local`

Hopefully this helps others that encounter this issue and are not willing to abandon Macports in order to solve it.

Comment: FWIW, I was unable to get it installed with this command on OSX 10.10, but the (longer, more explicit) version of the command by @zarthur worked in my environment. I'm mentioning this here in case someone else comes here looking for a solution.